# Getting return value from function is d

Tags: javascript

I am new to using AngularJS and JavaScript. After returning the value, I am getting `d` as a result. Am I calling the function correctly? Please tell me what I am doing wrong in the code below. Thanks in advance.
Here is my code:

```
     function volunteerNumbr (ProspectID){var value1;

        console.log("volunteerNumbr[i].ProspectID",ProspectID)
        $http.get(baseURL + 'participant/prospectid/'+ProspectID).success(function(participantData, status, headers, config){

            var participantData=JSON.stringify(participantData);

            if(JSON.parse(participantData) == null){
                value1 =  -1;
                //console.log ("$rootScope.value1",$rootScope.value);
            }
            else{
               value1 = JSON.parse(participantData).length;
                console.log ("$rootScope.value2",$rootScope.value);

            }
        }).error(function(data, status, header, config) {
                console.log("not fecthed")
            });

         console.log ("$rootScope.value3",value1);
         return value1;
    }



    $http.get(baseURL + 'prospect/all/').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.prospects = data;    //show data on list


        var prospect=JSON.stringify($scope.prospects);
        var prospect=JSON.parse(prospect);

        var prospectLength = prospect.length;

        for(var i = 0; i < prospectLength; i++){

            prospect[i].num = volunteerNumbr(prospect[i].ProspectID);


        }
        console.log("all prospect",prospect);



    }).error(function(data, status, header, config) {});
```

Comment: `Getting return value from function is d` could you elaborate more on this, not understanding your issue. which function are you talking about ?

Comment: the value in  prospect[i].num is showing  d every time the for loop execute where i am trying to return -1 or length of participantData.

Comment: You cannot assign $http.get to `prospect[i].num`. You have to assign its value gets success method. It is not clear what you are expecting from your code so nobody will be able to help you. Can you expand on what you need a little more or include more code?

Comment: Making Ajax call in a loop would not be a good idea.

Comment: i changed the code but now i am getting return value as undefined.please look above for the changed code

Comment: You should probably read up on the documentation, too. According to the [AngularJS Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) `$http.get` returns an `HttpPromise` for a future object.

Comment: @avi Your edit still wont work. `volunteerNumbr` will return before `value1` has been set. You could make it work by passing `prospect[i]` instead of `prospect[i].ProspectID` and just setting `.num` in the function instead of trying to return a value

Answer (score 0):

`$http.get()` actually returns you a promise object and not the data you return inside the `success()`,

so if you need to set the value `prospect[i].num` inside the success block like below 
Creat a function by enclosing the `$http.get` inside a **IIFE(Immediately Invoked Function Expression)** and pass the current index value inside for loop, so that that index value is contained for that ajax call.

**JS Code:**

```
$http.get(baseURL + 'prospect/all/').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
$scope.prospec = data;    //show data on list


var prospect=JSON.stringify($scope.prospec);
var prospect=JSON.parse(prospect);
//console.log("all prospect",prospect.length);
var prospectLength = prospect.length;

for(var i = 0; i < prospectLength; i++){

   // prospect[i].num  = volunteerNumbr(prospect[i].ProspectID);

      //Creating a IIFE and enclose the $http.get inside it
      (function (index) {
      $http.get(baseURL + 'participant/prospectid/'+prospect[i].ProspectID).success(function(participantData, status, headers, config){

        var participantData=JSON.stringify(participantData);
        if(JSON.parse(participantData) == null){
            prospect[index].num =-1;
             }
        else{
            prospect[i].num =JSON.parse(participantData).length;
                                }
    }).error(function(data, status, header, config) {
            console.log("error")
        });
     }(i));

     console.log("num",prospect[i].num);
      }
console.log("all prospect",prospect);
$scope.prospects= prospect;
console.log("all $scope.prospects",$scope.prospects);

}).error(function(data, status, header, config) {});
```

Comment: there is no guarantee that the ajax calls will complete in the same order, so we need to know which `ajax` calls `response` should should be stored against which location in `prospect` array, this is possible using `IIFE`, as the index value is contained within every anonymous function.

Comment: for better understanding check this jsfiddle and see what happens in console. http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/t3kcwc7y/222/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that. It makes sense now that I see it.